# How to remove file in terminal with ampersand in name?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I tried different escaping possibilities and still could not remove file with spaces and ampersand in name.

```
[23:36 @ ~] $ rm /Volumes/Storage/Music/pop/Nicole\ Kidman\ \&\ Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3 
[23:36 @ ~] $ rm /Volumes/Storage/Music/pop/Nicole\ Kidman\ \\&\ Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3 
[23:36 @ ~] $ rm /Volumes/Storage/Music/pop/Nicole\ Kidman\ &\ Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3 
[23:36 @ ~] $ rm /Volumes/Storage/Music/pop/Nicole\ Kidman\\ &\ Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3
[23:36 @ ~] $ rm /Volumes/Storage/Music/pop/Nicole\ Kidman\\ & Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3
[23:38 @ ~] $ rm "/Volumes/Storage/Music/pop/Nicole Kidman & Ewan Mcgregor - Come What May.mp3"
[23:38 @ ~] $ rm "/Volumes/Storage/Music/pop/Nicole Kidman \& Ewan Mcgregor - Come What May.mp3"
```

Autocomplete

[image]

With single quotes

[image]

OS: Mavericks 1.9.0

**EDIT:**

I don't know why, but when you use `/bin/rm` instead of `rm` it works fine, even if `rm` points to `/bin/rm`. (That's really weird)

```
[01:32 @ ~/test] $ which rm 
/bin/rm
[01:32 @ ~/test] $ rm Nicole\ Kidman\ \&\ Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3 
[1] 10930
-bash:  Ewan Mcgregor - Come What May.mp3: command not found
rm: Nicole Kidman : No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 1                  /bin/rm Nicole\ Kidman\ 
[01:32 @ ~/test] $ /bin/rm Nicole\ Kidman\ \&\ Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3
```

Comment: Why didn't you let autocomplete pick it up?

Comment: Are you sure the file exists and has that exact name? Autocomplete would find it if it did.

Comment: Autocomplete gave me as iTunes gave: "Nicole\ Kidman\ \&\ Ewan\ Mcgregor\ -\ Come\ What\ May.mp3" Which doesn't work

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams http://i.imgur.com/ckIeLy5.png

Comment: Looks like something is intercepting your commandline before passing it to the shell.  try wrapping the file's name in `'`s (single-quotes).

Comment: @DopeGhoti http://i.imgur.com/Lc6EH9V.png

Comment: Please add the extra information into the question itself rather than relying on people reading the comments.

Comment: If you replace the \& with a single '?' without quotes, it should work. (edited: should be a question mark, not a period)

Comment: try `/bin/rm` rather than just `rm`.  I suspect you have an alias set for `rm` that's getting in the way.

Comment: @DopeGhoti make your comment as an answer

Comment: Try `type rm` to see what `rm` really is. `which` doesn't show aliases and functions, but `type` does.

Comment: @message- done and done

Comment: You can use `alias rm` to see what your `rm` is aliased to.

Comment: Did you try double quotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/bin/rm` rather than just `rm`. I suspect you have an alias set for `rm` that's getting in the way.

Comment: alias rm='exec_scmb_expand_args /bin/rm' https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze modified `rm`, `mv` and other functions